# Possible to read CVV code with an NFC reader?

Tags: payment, contactless-smartcard, emv

Is CVV security code stored electronically in EMV debit cards? I am wondering if it's possible to process a payment using a NFC reader and an online gateway.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, CVV2 used in online transactions are not encoded anywhere inside the chip.